# NumberFormatException haciendo parseo

Tags: java, android

Tengo un método que recibe una serie de parámetros, uno de ellos es un valor de tipo Float y al intentar castearlo a un `int` me da fallo y casca la aplicación. El error se da en la tercera fila del método, donde declaro `cantidadIntroducidoI`.

Metodo:

```
public void cambioCompraValores(Float cantidadValores, int mediaInt) {

    Float cantidadIntroducidoF = cantidadValores;
    String cantidadIntroducidoS = String.valueOf(cantidadIntroducidoF);
    int cantidadIntroducidoI = Integer.parseInt(cantidadIntroducidoS);
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.iberd.actionvalue, PID: 9292
                                                                         java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "36.26"
                                                                             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                                                                             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                             at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment.cambioCompraValores(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:363)
                                                                             at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment.calculoValores(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:289)
                                                                             at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment.access$200(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:46)
                                                                             at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment$1.onClick(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:202)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Eso no es un cast, un cast es `(int)`.

Comment: bueno, pues un parseo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que no puedes parsear un número decimal a entero con la función `Integer.parseInt`

Esto lo puedes solucionar de varias formas:

-**Round()**: puedes utilizar la función `Math.round()` que te devolverá el entero más cercano al número a redondear. Ya sea mayor o menor.
Ejemplo:

```
float f = 100.6;
Int i = Math.round(f); // Devolverá 101
```

-**Floor()**: puedes utilizar la función `Math.floor()` que te devolverá el entero inferior más cercano al número a redondear.

```
float f = 100.6;
Int i = Math.floor(f); // Devolverá 100
```

-**Ceil()**: puedes utilizar la función `Math.ceil()` que te devolverá el entero superior más cercano al número a redondear.

```
float f = 100.6;
Int i = Math.ceil(f); // Devolverá 101
```

Por otra parte como dice @SJuan76 tienes una función propia de la clase **Float** que te devuelve el valor entero de un float, esta función es `intValue()` que tiene un comportamiento similar a la función `Math.round()`

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que obtienes la representación de un `Float` como `String`, que puede ser algo como "3.141592" o incluso "6.28+E28".

Ninguno de los valores arriba expresados puede ser convertido directamente a entero, y `valueOf` rechazará cualquier cosa que no sea un representación en `String` de un int.

Hay dos opciones:

- Analizar la representación del String. Con `indexOf` y `substring`, encontrar las partes del String y eliminar las que sobren para pasar un valor "limpio" a `valueOf`. Tendrás que tener en cuenta, por supuesto, el valor del exponente si lo hubiera.
- Leer el [javadoc de la clase Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html), y hacer:

  ```
  cantidadValores.intValue()
  ```

  Si te parece demasiado sencillo y/o quieres hacer un cast, también puedes hacer

  ```
  float valorFloat = cantidadValores;
  int cantidadIntroducidoI = (int) valorFloat.
  ```

Recomiendo la segunda opción...

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje definido en el LogCat indica el problema:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "36.26"

estas tratando de realizar un `parse` a entero de un valor tipo `String` que contiene un valor que solo puede parsear  a flotante.

en este caso lo ideal es redondear el valor al entero mas cercano mediante el uso del método **[round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-)**, que redondea un valor `float` o `doble` a el valor entero más cercano. :

**[Math.round()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-)**

tu método sería simplemente (te aconsejo agregar manejo de excepciones):

```
  public void cambioCompraValores(Float cantidadValores) {
        try {

            int cantidadIntroducidoI = Math.round(cantidadValores);

        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            Log.e("Error" , "NumberFormatException " + nfe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```