# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa es un conversor de unidades utilizando un 3 combox, el combo el principal que tiene como menu: Longitud, temperatura, frecuencia y presion y los 2 otros combox se encargan de convertir las unidades utilizando 2 cajas de textos, yo la verdad no se con q evento puedo trabajar para los 2 combox, de antemano le agradezco mucho a la persona o personas q me colabore en este es el programa:***

```
import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Conversor extends JFrame {

        public JPanel panel;
        private JLabel enunciado, enlazado;
        private JTextField conv1, conv2;
        private JComboBox Lista1, Lista2, Lista3;
        private JButton clear;
        //constructor

        public Conversor() {
            super("Conversor Unidades");
            setBounds(100, 200, 290, 300);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Panel();
            Enunciado();
            CajaTexto();
            boton();
            objetosCombox();
            lista3();
        }

        private void Panel() {
            panel = new JPanel();
            this.getContentPane().add(panel);
            panel.setLayout(null);
        }

        private void Enunciado() {
            enunciado = new JLabel("Este es un software para convertir unidades.");
            panel.add(enunciado);
            enunciado.setBounds(10, 2, 300, 35);
            enunciado.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
            enlazado = new JLabel("=");
            panel.add(enlazado);
            enlazado.setBounds(125, 80, 100, 25);
            enlazado.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        }

        private void CajaTexto() {
            //caja de texto 1
            conv1 = new JTextField();
            panel.add(conv1);
            conv1.setBounds(10, 80, 110, 25);
            //caja de texto 2
            conv2 = new JTextField();
            panel.add(conv2);
            conv2.setBounds(140, 80, 110, 25);
        }

        //funciones de los combox
        private void objetosCombox() {
            Lista3 = new JComboBox();
            Lista1 = new JComboBox();
            Lista2 = new JComboBox();
            Lista3.setBounds(10, 40, 240, 30);
            Lista1.setBounds(10, 120, 110, 25);
            Lista2.setBounds(140, 120, 110, 25);
            panel.add(Lista3);
            panel.add(Lista1);
            panel.add(Lista2);
            Lista3.addItemListener(new menu3());
            Lista1.addItemListener(new evento1());
            Lista2.addItemListener(new evento1());
        }

        private void lista3() {
            Lista3.addItem("Longitud");
            Lista3.addItem("Temperatura");
            Lista3.addItem("Frecuencia");
            Lista3.addItem("Presion");
        }

        private class menu3 implements ItemListener {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                rellenaCombo1((String) Lista3.getSelectedItem());
            }
        }

        private void rellenaCombo1(String SeleccionCombo1) {
            Lista1.removeAllItems();
            Lista2.removeAllItems();
            if (SeleccionCombo1.equals("Longitud")) {
                Lista1.addItem("Km");
                Lista1.addItem("m");
                Lista1.addItem("Cm");
                Lista1.addItem("Pulgada");
                Lista1.addItem("Millas");
                //menu 2
                Lista2.addItem("Km");
                Lista2.addItem("m");
                Lista2.addItem("Cm");
                Lista2.addItem("Pulgada");
                Lista2.addItem("Millas");
            }

            if (SeleccionCombo1.equals("Temperatura")) {
                Lista1.addItem("Grados Celsius");
                Lista1.addItem("Grados Fahrenheit");
                Lista1.addItem("Grados Kelvin");
                // menu 2
                Lista2.addItem("Grados Celsius");
                Lista2.addItem("Grados Fahrenheit");
                Lista2.addItem("Grados Kelvin");

            }
            if (SeleccionCombo1.equals("Frecuencia")) {
                Lista1.addItem("Herz");
                Lista1.addItem("KiloHerz");
                Lista1.addItem("MegaHerz");
                Lista1.addItem("GigaHerz");
                //menu 2
                Lista2.addItem("Herz");
                Lista2.addItem("KiloHerz");
                Lista2.addItem("MegaHerz");
                Lista2.addItem("GigaHerz");
            }
            if (SeleccionCombo1.equals("Presion")) {
                Lista1.addItem("Atmosfera");
                Lista1.addItem("Bar");
                Lista1.addItem("Psi");
                Lista1.addItem("Pascal");
                Lista1.addItem("Tor");
                // menu 2
                Lista2.addItem("Atmosfera");
                Lista2.addItem("Bar");
                Lista2.addItem("Psi");
                Lista2.addItem("Pascal");
                Lista2.addItem("Tor");
            }
        }

        private class evento1 implements ItemListener {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                   String longitud = (String) Lista3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 if (longitud.equals("Longitud")) {
                    String magnitud = (String) Lista1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if (magnitud.equals("Km")) {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(conv1.getText());
                        String magnitud1 = (String)Lista2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (magnitud1.equals("Km")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error no se puede convertir de Km a Km");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
            private void boton() {
                clear = new JButton("Clear");
                panel.add(clear);
                clear.setBounds(85, 160, 80, 25);
                clear.addActionListener(new clear7());
            }

            class clear7 implements ActionListener {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == clear) {
                        conv1.setText("");
                        conv2.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Este es el error:

> ```
>     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at Conversor7.Conversor$evento1.itemStateChanged(Conversor.java:158)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1280)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:131)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem(JComboBox.java:716)
>       at Conversor7.Conversor.rellenaCombo1(Conversor.java:100)
>       at Conversor7.Conversor.access$300(Conversor.java:16)
>       at Conversor7.Conversor$menu3.itemStateChanged(Conversor.java:92)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1280)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:131)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem(JComboBox.java:716)
>       at Conversor7.Conversor.lista3(Conversor.java:82)
>       at Conversor7.Conversor.<init>(Conversor.java:34)
>       at Conversor7.PrincipalConversor.main(PrincipalConversor.java:4)
>     C:\Users\JORGE\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> ```
>
> Java returned: 1
>           BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Cual es la linea 158 de la clase Conversor?

Comment: segun el codigo q plasme arriba la linea 158 es este codigo:                        
String magnitud1 = (String)Lista2.getSelectedItem().toString(); el error del codigo es este: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [NumberFormatException haciendo parseo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73988/numberformatexception-haciendo-parseo)

Answer (score 0):

El error

> NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

se debe a que estas intentando convertir un valor no numérico a numérico

Agrega el método que te servirá para validar los casos en los cuales el valor que se encuentra en el `JTextField` llamado `conv1` no es de tipo numérico:

```
public static int checkNumerico(String numero){
    int resultado = 0; //Valor predeterminado 0
    try{
        if(numero != null){
            resultado = Integer.parseInt(numero);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("Error NumberFormatException value: " + numero);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

de esta forma usarías el método :

```
//int num1 = Integer.parseInt(conv1.getText());
int num1 = checkNumerico(conv1.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa bien lo que dice tu error, la excepción `NumberFormatException` significa que la cadena tiene un formato numérico no valido, despues te muestra la entrada que recibió la función `Integer.parseInt()` la cual fue `""` , es decir una cadena vacía por lo cual no se puede parsear una cadena vacía a entero, te recomiendo verifiques el valor que le das a `conv1` ya que no lo esta obteniendo el método, para evitar este error puedes revisar primero si la variable no este vacia:

```
private class evento1 implements ItemListener {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                   String longitud = (String) Lista3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 if (longitud.equals("Longitud")) {
                    String magnitud = (String) Lista1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if (magnitud.equals("Km")) {
                        //Validacion
                        if(conv1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error elemento vacio");
                        } else {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(conv1.getText());
                        String magnitud1 = (String)Lista2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        }
                        if (magnitud1.equals("Km")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error no se puede convertir de Km a Km");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la atencion, te comento q me sale un error antes era con el For input String ya ahora me sale el error asi:                                         
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException                              el error me apunta en este codigo:                                                                                            String magnitud1 = (String)Lista2.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Lo mas probable es que tu lista Lista2 este inicializada en null y al llamar al método getSelectedItem() lanza esta excepción, verifica si tu lista se esta inicializando correctamente

Comment: diculpame que te pregunte esto yo no soy muy experto con programacion en Java yo estoy estudiando Java por mi cuenta, como se inicializa una Lista?

Comment: Perdon por la demora, inicializas tus variables de Lista en los metodos de rellenarCombo y en el objetosCombo, tal cual es la expresion Lista3 = new JComboBox(), por ejemplo, revisa el orden de ejecucion de tus metodos para que cuando llegue a itemStateChange ya tenga algun valor tu variable